# Is it possible to load a pdf into my iOS app from iBooks?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdf, ibooks

I have an app that I'm using to create a custom PDF document (containing an image). I'm using my app the save the PDF into iBooks. I would like to be able to later access iBooks and get a copy of the document again.
I know that because of sandboxing, you used to not be able to load documents from iBooks into my iOS app. However, you weren't able to open PDFs with iBooks before and now you are - so is there a workout around for picking my own PDFs out of iBooks and loading them back into the app?
If not, how would I go about doing this? Are there examples or tutorials somewhere? (I'd like to select my own previously-saved pdf, from the same app, from iBooks like I'm able to select an image from the photo roll)

thank you!

Comment: I still feel you can't do it and there doesn't seem to be a workaround

Comment: ok thank you. I'll try to find another approach.

Answer (score 0):

iBooks are developed using iBooks Author, not Xcode. In addition, iBooks are for use with the iBooks application that is available for newer versions of iOS. They are not meant to be used within an iOS application.

So, sorry for the sad news. You can not integrate iBooks with your iOS apps.

Comment: Oh, I didn't explain this enough, so sorry. What I'm trying to get access to is PDF documents that I will be saving into iBooks previously from the same app - so they're not actual books, but custom PDFs I've created.

Comment: You can not get access to anything from iBooks in your app.

Comment: Is it still same? I wanted to make similar thing.

Comment: Yes. Its still the same.